# AspectJ ITDs : introduction of methods dynamically based on reflection

Tags: java, reflection, aop, aspectj

is it possible to introduce methods definition on a interface using AspectJ dynamically based on methods defined in another using reflection API ?

for example:
giving an interface A

```
public interface A {
    Integer getNext();
}
```

i want to introduce the same method name into interface B with another return type like so:

```
public interface B {
    Property<Integer> getNext();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this by using an annotation processor, which AspectJ now supports. The annotation processor would discover the method in A and could generate an aspect that introduces the method into B. An example annotation processor that generates an Aspect is here:

https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-182.html

All this would be done at compile time (not sure that is dynamic enough for you).